# SQL Order By with column, which has numbers and Letters separately

Tags: sql

The data looks like this when I do an `ORDER BY` in SQL.

```
ColumnName  
----------
1  
100  
10000  
25  
30  
33  
7000  
ABC  
XZY
```

I want the order by to work like this.

```
ColumnName  
----------
10000  
7000  
100   
33   
30   
25  
1   
ABC   
XYZ
```

First order by the numeric value and then by the letters.

Comment: In ORDER BY, use LIKE or similar to distinguish numeric from text, cast numeric values, order by that desc, order by other asc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution for *SQL-Server*.

You can use `CASE`. When values are numeric convert it to `INT` and order by - descending, otherwise if values are not numeric, order by - ascending.

**QUERY**

```
SELECT ColumnName
FROM tbl
ORDER BY CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(ColumnName) = 1 THEN CAST(ColumnName AS INT) END DESC,
         CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(ColumnName) = 0 THEN col END ASC
```

*Note:* you have to convert numeric values to datatype `INT` to achieve correct order. If you try to order numeric values stored as varchar you will get incorrect results. For example:

If we use descending order then '10000' will go after '7000', that because first symbol `1` of '10000' is lower then `7` of '7000' varchar value. So It will be:

```
7000
10000
```

---

**DEMO**

You can test It at <kbd>[**SQL FIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9f5d3/1)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Using this solution:

```
SELECT someColum as sort, someColumn, otherColums... 
WHERE someOther = 'somevalue' 
ORDER BY sort ASC, (someColumn +0) ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by following SQL query:

```
SELECT ColumnName 
FROM tbl
ORDER BY CAST(ColumnName as UNSIGNED) DESC, ColumnName ASC;
```